# How do you target the html/css of function instances uniquely?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, object

Can you target new instances of an object uniquely without passing them an id as a parameter?

If you create new objects from a constructor and each instance has access to some html (presentation) stored as a variable in the constructor, when new instances of the object are created and html is output from the presentation variable, how do you target each of these instances in a unique way? How could you style one instance differently from the other?

```js
function MyObj() {
  this.content = "<div class = 'someclass'>Some text </div>";
}

var newObj1 = new MyObj();
console.log(newObj1.content); //outputs Some text 

var newObj2 = new MyObj();
console.log(newObj2.content); //outputs Some text
```

If you wanted to target the css of all new classes you could use:

```
var target1 = $('.someclass').css('color,'orange');
```

But how to target one differently from the other?

Comment: By using an id?

Comment: You really need to learn the basics of HTML, CSS, and Javascript.

Comment: @Luca Try reading the question

Comment: @Seblor And you need to learn the basics of politeness.

Comment: @stacker My comment was not meant to be rude, but honest. Sorry if you took it that way. Because either I do not understand your question at all, or you are a beginner in web dev.

Comment: @Seblor No problem the question IS poorly phrased.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass in something that is unique to acknowledge each object. Below I pass in a name to be added to the elements `class` attribute.

Note if you are using the CSS elsewhere then this is fine, but if it's just used once then why not add an `id` to distinguish the areas uniquely. That is, that is what an `id` is meant for.

```js
function MyObj(name) {
  if(name != undefined) {
    this.content = "<div class = 'default " + name + "'>Some text </div>";
  } else {
    this.content = "<div class = 'default'>Some text </div>";
  }
}

var newObj1 = new MyObj('blue-rows');
console.log(newObj1.content); //outputs Some text 

var newObj2 = new MyObj('orange-rows');
console.log(newObj2.content); //outputs Some text

var newObj3 = new MyObj();
console.log(newObj3.content); //outputs Some text

var container = document.getElementById('container');

container.innerHTML += newObj1.content;
container.innerHTML += newObj2.content;
container.innerHTML += newObj3.content;
```

```css
.default {
  color: red;
}

.blue-rows {
  color: blue;
}

.orange-rows {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
</div>
```

Comment: I'm marking this as correct as it has answered the question as written. Its not really what I meant by I guess I have not expressed it properly in the question. The idea was how to distinguish object instances (in this case to reference their css but it could be for any reason) without passing in a unique identifier. It seems this is not possible. If you do pass one in in then obviously it should be an id as people have noted.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how you'd like to target the other instance. One option is to use the `:nth-child`, `:first-child`, or `:last-child` selectors. As an example:

```
$('.someclass:nth-child(even)').css('color','orange');
$('.someclass:nth-child(odd)').css('color','blue');
$('.someclass:nth-child(1)').css('color','green');
$('.someclass:first-child').css('color','red');
```